# Magento 2: Permission issue with generated directory

Tags: magento2, theme, installation, permissions, aws

I'm having issues installing a theme due to the **'generated'** directory **not generating** all of the files that need to be generated after I run command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Which I think is linked to **permission issues** (the generated directories have a default permission set to 775).

Because the generated folders are set to `775 permission`, there is no 'write' permission for the other user (magento) and thus  crashes instead of upgrading the new `theme/modules`.

I cannot run the command line as a root user as it uses `cgi/fgi` instead of cli. I end up having to run as the centos user which uses cli (magento's command line interface) If I could run cli commands as root user. I that would overcome the permission issues that prevents the 'generated' directory from generating all of the files and thus install modules and themes instead of throwing script errors.

I know **magento 2.2.6** is relatively new and I'm probably facing an isolated issue given that the environment I'm running magento on is unique:  aws instance with whm in the middle to provide greater flexibility and provide a cpanel interface.

Comment: This is exactly why Magento says you should setup Magento2 as a user on the server that has the correct group and permissions

Answer (score 7):

### Magento 2 recommended folder and file permission

Please follow following terminal commands for folder and file permission.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find var pub/static pub/media  generated/ app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;

find var pub/static pub/media generated/ app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**It worked like charm**

Answer (score 7):

It' sometimes happen, that after run any command bin/magento your generated folder has changed ovnership to youruser:youruser, but should be youruser:www-data (for apache2 for example).

To fix that run in magento directory:

```
sudo chown -R youruser:www-data .
```

and:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data youruser
```

after this you will never have this problem after running magento commands.

> The -a -G options are important because they add apache or www-data as
>   a secondary group to the user account, which preserves the user’s
>   primary group. Adding a secondary group to a user account helps
>   restrict file ownership and permissions to ensure members of a shared
>   group only have access to certain files.

You can check this by running now:

```
php bin/magento c:f


ls -l generated/code
```

all ovnership should stay same so youruser:www-data

Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 0):

Give 777 permission to  **generated** directory

Answer (score 0):

You must read this [article](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/rc_perms.html) from [Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/rc_perms.html), where say exactly what you want about the permissions.

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2 && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running selinux be sure to set the permissions for it.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/path/to/your/magentofiles/generated(/.*)?'
restorecon -Rv '/path/to/your/magentofiles/'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have installed a fresh Magento 2.3 setup on Windows 10 and getting permission issues. I solved it by following steps.

1. Go to > app > etc > di.xml file and find this code 
    Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
    Then replace with below code.

   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
2. Go to vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator then fix the real 
   pate like this:

   $realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
3. Now run following commands:
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    php bin/magento s:s:d -f
    php bin/magento c:c
4. After running step 3 if you got blank page then please remove/rename global.php file 
   from generated\metadata\

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give proper permission and Don't give 777 permission as it is not recommended

try the bellow commands

```
    find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
    find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
    
    sudo chown -R :<web server group> . 

    chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the generated directory and using below command and then run

> php bin/magento setup:upgarde
> command, then it should be works.

Remove generated Directory

```
sudo rm -rf generated/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the below command.

```
chmod 777 -R generated/*
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER && sudo chmod -R 777 YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER
```